# Solucion al error con rest_framework_filters Django

Tags: django, djangorestframework, django-urls

El error es:

> error Could not import
> 'rest_framework_filters.backends.DjangoFilterBackend' for API setting
> 'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS'

Esto sucede porque después de la versión 1 de rest_framework_filters se le implemento su propio backend "RestFrameworkFilterBackend" en lugar del de django "DjangoFilterBackend"

https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters#filterset-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución esta en tener instalada la actualización más reciente, en mi caso desde pipfile.

```
[packages]
djangorestframework = "==3.9.*"
mysqlclient = "*"
pytz = "*"
scipy = "*"
"urllib3" = "*"
Django = "==2.*"
django-filter = "==2.2.*"
djangorestframework-filters = "==1.0.0.dev2"
```

Vital usar RestFrameworkFilterBackend

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'rest_framework_filters',...
],
'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': [
            'rest_framework_filters.backends.RestFrameworkFilterBackend',
        ],
```

Asegurarse de actualizar los filtros cuando importamos.

De DjangoFilters

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import FilterSet,...
```

para usar django-rest-framework-filters

```
from rest_framework_filters import FilterSet, NumberFilter, RelatedFilter, ...
```

Con este uso podemos filtrar relaciones como la siguiente

Control de calidad

```
class ControlRutinario(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    //Un control existe en un lote
    muestra = models.OneToOneField('Muestra', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rcr = models.FloatField(verbose_name='RECOBRO criterio 90-110% recuperacion')
```

Las muestras tienen un lote

```
class Muestra(models.Model):
    dqo = models.ForeignKey('LoteDQO', null=True, blank=True,
                        related_name='muestras', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Lote(BaseBatch):
    # Relación genérica al sample
    param_samples = GenericRelation('common.ParamSampleBatch',
                                    related_query_name='dqo_batch')
```

Serializamos

```
    class LoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
        class Meta:
            model = models.ControlRutinario
            fields = '__all__'
        lote = serializers.IntegerField(source='muestra.dqo_id', read_only=True)
```

El filtrado para saber el resultado del recobro del control rutinario por id del Lote

```
class _ParamLOTEaDQO(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Muestra
        fields = ['dqo']


class _ParamMuestraDQOControlFilterSet(FilterSet):
    # RelatedFilter para obtner el id del lote segun DQO5->Muestra->Lote
    lote = RelatedFilter(_ParamLOTEaDQO,  field_name='muestra', queryset=models.Muestra.objects.all())


class DQO5ViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.DQO5.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.DQO5erializer
    filterset_class = _ParamMuestraDQOControlFilterSet
```

Ahora con el RelatedFilter podemos filtrar
?lote=&lote__dqo=658

```
> GET /app/api/dqo5/?lote=&lote__dqo=658
> HTTP 200 OK Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS Content-Type:
> application/json Vary: Accept
> 
> [
>     {
>         "id": 661,
>         "lote": 658,
>         "fecha": "2022-03-18",
>         "v2": 6.9,
>         "v1_v2": 2.5,
>         "vol": 5.0,
>         "mgl": 484.0,
>         "valor_real": 500.0,
>         "recobro": 96.8,
>         "muestra": 7967
>     } ]
```